# Count even XOR sum of subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, xor, sub-array

We are given an array as an input and we have to count the number continuous sub-arrays with even XOR sum.
My approach to this question is extremely naive.I used two loops to get sub-arrays and get their XOR sum.
The following code in python describes my algorithm:

```
t = int(input())
for i in range(t):
    n = int(input())
    arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    output = 0 
  
    if arr == []:
        print(0)
    else:
        for i in range(0,n):
             
            xorSum = 0 
            for j  in range(i,n):
                
                xorSum = xorSum ^ arr[j]
      
            
                if (xorSum%2 == 0):
                    output+=1
        print(output)
```

Inputs:
The first line   is no. of testcases
The next line is the size of the array
The third line is the elements of array separated by " "(Space)
Output:
The output is no. of sub-arrays

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure I understand the question correctly so let me rephrase: Each line is an array of 0, 1 numbers, repeated N times. You are looking for subarrays with even XOR sum. Here is where I get lost: what do you mean by a continuous subarray? Subarray can be  x[0:5] as well as x[3:7]. When are subarrays continuous?

Comment: Each line is an array containing integers and not only binary numbers.

Comment: Ok. And what does continuous array mean please? Also, two numbers XORed are even as long as either both or none of them even - so you are basically just xoring their last bit anyways.